# Facing Crash error or Redirecting to Mainactivity when clicking on Signup button and login both

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I don't know why I am getting error on login and sign up activity with firebase.

Problem what I am facing is - whenever i click on signup button or in login button its start crashing sometimes and sometimes its redirect me to Mainactivity.class.

my Signupactivity.class

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivitySignUpBinding binding;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setTitle("Creating Account");
        progress.setMessage("We're Creating your Account");


        binding.btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                progress.show();
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
                        (binding.edEmail.getText().toString() , binding.edPassword.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        userModels user = new userModels
                                (binding.edUsername.getText().toString() , binding.edEmail.getText().toString() , binding.edPassword.getText().toString());

                        String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                        database.getReference().child("Users").child(id).setValue(user);

                        progress.dismiss();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this , LoginActivty.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else  {
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Authentication faild", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        binding.tvRegister.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this , LoginActivty.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help.